# Why can Visualforce code not be obfuscated in subscriber org for a managed package?

Tags: managed-package

I just realized that Visualforce code is not my company's intellectual property at all. I am quite new in developing managed packages and noticed this today. I understand the validation rules, formula etc. are visible by subscribers as they are part of configuration, but VF is also code, why is it not protected? (Just out of curiosity).
Referring link [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_protect_ip.htm).

Answer (score 2):

While I don't really know *why*, you always have the option of putting everything sensitive in a protected Visualforce component, and then just using the Visualforce page as a wrapper container that includes the component.

Comment: I already did that:) But thanks anyway. Looks very strange so asked the question...